# C++: Assigning pointers in a class to NULL before calling "delete"

Tags: c++

Is it necessary to assign all pointers in a class to NULL before deleting? I mean, from example, for the following snippets of a function that deletes a node in a binary search tree,

**1.**

```
Node *temp = parent->left;
parent->left = temp->left;
delete temp;
```

**2.**

```
Node *temp = parent->left;
parent->left = temp->left;
temp->left = NULL;
delete temp;
```

Is the line

```
temp->left = NULL;
```

necessary? Some tutorials do it while others don't.

Comment: Not neceesary.  Only necessary if there is a risk that other code will later come across a free'd pointer that is non-null.

Comment: It depends - will your node destructor do anything with the pointer if you leave it, e.g. recursively clean up a node you might want to keep?

Comment: no, the destructor is default

Comment: You should just use [modern C++ style](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp) and not worry about it. Related: [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: +1 for modern C++ style, very comprehensive source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends. If the destructor of `Node` deletes the child nodes, then it is necessary. If it doesn't then that line is not necessary. Yet some tutorials might include it solely in order to promote a good programming style. If you introduce a bug to your program and use the pointer after deleting it, then having a null pointer will give you an error message instead of undefined behavior. You might also want to add the line `temp = NULL;` if you want to follow this style more rigorously.

Comment: +1. I (and all other answers to date) missed this possibility

Comment: After delete temp; accessing temp->left is undefined in the first place, and having set temp->left = NULL before the deletion of temp doesn't save you from that.

Comment: Could you perhaps illustrate how it could be necessary?

Comment: How what could be necessary?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Trivial. `Node::~Node() { delete this->left; }`. Not a good idea, of course (risks stack overflow) but technically legal and leak-free. With that style, deleting the head node deletes the entire list.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: Using a nulled pointer after deletion is just as UB as using a non-nulled pointer after deletion.

Comment: @MSalters I'm not quiet sure what UB means, but setting a pointer to null after deleting it can make a lot of sense. That's one of the reasons `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are set to null when they are reset. They don't just delete, but also set to zero. Usually it will not cost you anything in release mode, since nulling a pointer will easily be optimized away by any modern compiler.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: UB = Undefined Behavior. Dereferencing either a deleted pointer or a null pointer is UB. The benefit of a null pointer  is that you can actually test whether it´s null.

Answer (score 4):

It probably isn't necessary.  No code can safely dereference `temp` after it has been deleted.  As noted by Ralph Tandetzky however, it is valid if `Node` has a destructor which operates on its `left` member

One other possible benefit of `NULL`ing its members is to catch invalid access more predictably.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not needed, but if the memory pointed to by `left` pointer is owned by the object, you should **delete** it in turn.

Comment: Dangerous comment: you shouldn't call `free(node->left)` in C++. In the worst case, you `delete` it. `malloc/free` is C style. Modern C++ style uses smart pointers, or just `std::list<>`

Answer (score 1):

No the line

> temp->left = NULL;

is not necessary. In many cases it can be helpful if you force yourself to add this line after every delete because you will be able to easily identify the error if your program crashes and you see the pointer set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly necessary, this is a measure designed to help in debugging. Imagine that you left that pointer without a `NULL` (e.g., in a linked list), and somehow you stepped into memory that has been freed, but its contents have not been deleted. Then there exists the danger that you can follow that pointer, without actually knowing whether it still exists or not, and maybe trying to delete that memory when it has already been deleted.

So, it is just safety, not something designed to achieve any functionality.

There is another (complementary) way to achieve the same: detect whether the memory being accessed has been deleted or not. For example:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node()
        { status = 0xf00dbeef; }
    ~Node()
        { status = 0xdeadbeef; }
    // ...
private:
    int status;

    bool isAlive() const
        { return ( status == 0xfoodbeef ); }
};
```

This way, you can always assure that you are using memory that was correctly allocated, i.e. it was a) not freed and b) it actually stores a `Node` object.

Hope this helps.